# Using Documentum DQL to get contents of all users' worklows

Tags: documentum

I know almost nothing about Documentum, so there are probably omissions in the information you need to answer my questions.  But I'm going to try, anyway...

We use Documentum (obviously).  Within Documentum, users can create workflows.  These workflows contain ordered lists of services that are used to process data.  So, we may have `ServiceA`, `ServiceB`, `ServiceC`, `ServiceD`, and `ServiceE`, and a user can create a workflow that says to process the data using, in order: `ServiceC`, `ServiceA`, and `ServiceB`.  Another user's list might be: `ServiceA`, `ServiceD`, `ServiceE`.

I've been asked to find a way to get a list containing the id/name of each user, the user's workflow id (name?), and items within the workflow.  From what I've read here on StackOverflow and elsewhere, it looks like this is possible via DQL.

And, if I have the DQL, it turns out that this will be simple to do using interfaces we've already built. If it's too complex, I'll need to write Java and use the API.  I'd prefer the DQL.. :-)

So, can someone here provide me with a pointer to a reference on DQL, and perhaps some pointers on what to look at/for?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need more than one DQL-Query. However, I would strongly recommend writing some DFC code and iterating over the results.

I would suggest to have a look in the Documentum Content Server Object Reference to find out more about the attributes of type `dm_workflow` (and, of course, related types like `dmi_workitem`, `dmc_workqueue`, etc.).

These types should provide the information you are looking for and where you might start best.